# Is it possible to switch sdk version in macOS

Tags: macos, xcode

I am now using `Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk`, some software need to build with some lower version of sdk, is it possible to switch the sdk to lower version? should I install different version of Xcode?

Is it possible to just switch the sdk without different version of Xcode because the Xcode is too large.

Comment: Yes, you can set the target OS version in your project's build settings.

Answer (score 3):

For the GUI Xcode application, you can change your project's Deployment Target version and Xcode should adjust the SDK used accordingly.

[image: Xcode Deployment Target 12.0]

For compiling using different SDKs on the command line, you can use `xcode-select`:

```
Usage: xcode-select [options]

Print or change the path to the active developer directory. This directory
controls which tools are used for the Xcode command line tools (for example,
xcodebuild) as well as the BSD development commands (such as cc and make).

Options:
  -h, --help                  print this help message and exit
  -p, --print-path            print the path of the active developer directory
  -s <path>, --switch <path>  set the path for the active developer directory
  --install                   open a dialog for installation of the command line developer tools
  -v, --version               print the xcode-select version
  -r, --reset                 reset to the default command line tools path
```

You can find historical Xcode Command Line Tools packages on Apple's [Additional Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Command%20Line%20Tools%20for%20Xcode) page (Apple ID sign-in required).